# Find all $f$ such that $\mathbb{E}[f(X)Y] = 0$

Tags: functions, expected-value, orthogonality

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with finite mean and variance. We seek to find all measurable $f$ such that $\mathbb{E}[f(X) Y] = 0$, where $\mathbb{E}$ denotes the expectation with respect to $X$ and $Y$.

Could someone help me prove this claim? A suggestion or the proof itself would both be helpful.

Comment 1: the set of functions $\{ h(X)\mathbb{E}[Y] - \mathbb{E}[h(X)Y] : h \text{ measurable}\}$ is contained within the class. I suspect it could be the full class.

Comment 2: this problem arose from my attempts to verify a separate claim and is now of independent interest to me.

My background: I'm familiar with real analysis, measure theory, probability theory.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hi @Shaun, thanks for the welcome. I'm not sure what else you want me to add. I've stated a conjecture I've found which can immediately be shown to be a subset of the class of all $f$. I haven't been able to show it's all such $f$ or make any such progress.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you studying?
What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise?
What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with?
What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else?
Is this question something you think should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Comment: I don't see any info about $X$.  And it is not clear why you write $g(Y)$ with no assumptions on $g$ or $Y$, why not call $g(Y)$ simply $Z$?

Comment: Thanks @Michael. That's a good point, (the $Z$-only case and the $g(Y)$ case are equivalent). I've updated the question.

Comment: @Michael No, I don't want to assume they're independent. Why do you say it's false? We see that $\mathbb{E} \left[ \left\{ h(X)\mathbb{E}[Y] - \mathbb{E}[h(X)Y] \right\} Y \right] = \mathbb{E}[h(X)Y]\mathbb{E}[Y] - \mathbb{E}[h(X)Y]\mathbb{E}[Y] = 0$.

Comment: @Michael Thanks, yes, the goal is to find all $f$ so that $\mathbb{E}[f(X)Y] = 0$

Comment: You would need to assume expectations exist, for example $E[Yh(X)]$.  Also if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $E[Y]=0$ then any $f$ for which $E[f(X)]$ is finite would work, whereas your class of functions in comment 1 reduces to only constant functions.

Comment: @Michael Good point about assuming the expected values exist. I've edited in a comment that they're in $L_2$. I'm not sure why you say the class is constant when $X$ and $Y$ are independent. The functions $\mathbb{E}[Y] \left( h(X) - \mathbb{E}[h(X)] \right)$ are not constant due the ``$h(X)$'' term which makes them nonconstant in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given random variables $X$ and $Y$.  You want all measurable $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy $E[f(X)Y]=0$.

**Assumption 1:** There is a measurable function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that
$E[g(X)Y] \neq 0$ and is finite.

Under Assumption 1, define $C$ as the class of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy
$$ f(x) = E[g(X)Y]h(x) - E[h(X)Y]g(x) \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$
for some measurable function $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for which $E[h(X)Y]$ exists and is finite.

It is easy to see that $f \in C$ if and only if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function that satisfies $E[f(X)Y]=0$.

To test if Assumption 1 holds we can try:

- $g(X)=1$:  This works if $E[Y]\neq 0$ and is finite.
- $g(X)=X$: This works if $E[XY]\neq 0$ and is finite.
- $g(X)=X^2$: This works if $E[X^2Y] \neq 0$ and is finite.

and so on. If Assumption 1 fails then all measurable functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for which $E[f(X)Y]$ exists and is finite satsify $E[f(X)Y]=0$. This holds, for example, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $E[Y]=0$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on the "it's easy to see..." part? The reverse direction there is the crux of my question. (I appreciate the clarity that your $g$ brings.)

Comment: If $f$ is measurable and satisfies $E[f(X)Y]=0$ then define $h(x)=f(x)/E[g(X)Y]$.